# IntelliJ IDEA does not create artifacts from pom.xml

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I use the IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4 under Windows and Linux (Ubuntu). The Maven plugin is installed.

I have a big maven project with many poms. Under Windows the IDEA creates artifacts automatically when I do reimport from maven. But under my Linux system the list of artifacts is empty always.

Is it a bug? How to generate artifacts in the Linux case?

Comment: Solution: I did reinstallation of maven integration plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Maven-Projects-View and click "package" for your aggregator project. IntelliJ will then run Maven which creates all artifacts in the target folder. If you run "install", these artifacts will be copied to the local repository. Maybe you didn't do that under Linux yet, so your repository is empty - under Windows, I suppose that IntelliJ was smart enough to refer to those artifacts while importing the project. I personally do not know of any feature in IntelliJ that would automatically package/install all projects on reimport - I'd consider this rather annyoing.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I run `mvn install` many times. I tell about IntellyJ "Artifact" section into "Project structure" dialog.

Comment: @dev.brutus: Ok. Interesting - I'm using IJ and Maven for years and never needed that artifact view. I confused it with the view of the dependent jars. May I ask what you are trying to achieve in that view? Maybe there is an easier way to do what you want.